# clear selection from v-autocomplete vuetify component

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to clear a selection from  but when I select an option then select the text input and press backspace the option it's reselected, from there if I delete the text again the  empty and works fine, how can I clear the selection and  text without deleting the v-text-field text twice?? here is the component I'm using:

```
 <v-autocomplete
            :items="itemsDestino"
            @input="emits('emitDestino', $event.target.value)"
            label="Destino..."
            prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker"
        >
            <template v-slot:item="{ item, props }">
                <v-list-item
                    :="props"
                    @click="emits('emitirSeleccion', (item.value += '-D-'))"
                ></v-list-item>
            </template>
        </v-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the select automatically takes the set model, when you try to delete the text, hence it just updates the text to what you specified there.

You could clear the model when you delete the text to make sure it isn't there anymore via a function or maybe the clearable prop, or if you want to have the possibility to choose multiple options, you have to specify that via the multiple props.

Comment: found a workaround using clearable prop and emiting an event with an empty string